# Python: wxPython: Help on GridBagSizer Layout Management

Tags: python, layout, wxpython

I got an problem trying to resize the controls, could someone point out where needs correction for a tidy controls stack up?

i.e. the TextCtrl boxes should be standard default sizes.

and The Read & Set buttons to be stacked just right below the TextCtrl boxes.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my code:

```
class AVMCPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        #create the grouping box and sizer for the outline
        self.box = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "AVMC CONTROL PANEL")
        self.bsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.box, wx.VERTICAL)

        #create the sizer and place controls within box
        self.gbs = wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)

        self.sampleList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'] #temp list items
        self.t1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Power Rail to margin:")
        self.lb1 = wx.ListBox(self, 1, (100, 50), (150, 120), self.sampleList, wx.LB_SINGLE)
        self.t2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Read Voltage:")
        self.t3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Set Voltage:")
        self.read_btn = wx.Button(self, 1, "  Read  ", (-1,-1) )
        self.set_btn = wx.Button(self, 1, "  Set  ", (-1,-1))
        self.rtext = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1, "", size=(80, -1), style=wx.ALL)
        self.stext = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1, "", size=(80, -1), style=wx.ALL)

        self.gbs.Add(self.t1, (0,0))
        self.gbs.Add(self.lb1, (1,0))
        self.gbs.Add(self.t2, (0,5))
        self.gbs.Add(self.t3, (0,10))
        self.gbs.Add(self.read_btn, (2,5))
        self.gbs.Add(self.set_btn, (2,10))
        self.gbs.Add(self.rtext, (1,5))
        self.gbs.Add(self.stext, (1,10))


        #Place the control inside group box
        self.bsizer.Add(self.gbs, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        #Place the static group box sizer within the border frame
        #Creating a border that the static box will sit inside
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.bsizer, 1000, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(self.border)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code:

```
self.rtext = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1, "", size=(80, -1), style=wx.ALL)
self.stext = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1, "", size=(80, -1), style=wx.ALL)
```

You are using a Sizer flag on a TextCtrl. Remove this to prevent the TextCtrl from being vertically taller.

Your buttons are going down because the ListBox is widening the row above it. Make the ListBox span over two rows with the following:

```
self.gbs.Add(self.lb1, (1,0), span=wx.GBSpan(2,1))
```